# Wireless printer and wireless internet on shared wi-fi network

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have to set up some laptops for internet and printer access in a hotel. There's already a shared wi-fi network there, so internet access should be easy.

A wireless printer is the obvious solution for printing, but it occurs to me that many of these shared wi-fi networks require you to register through a web page before it will work, and I don't see how you could do that on a printer. Or maybe that's just for internet access.

I read that some wireless printers can set up ad-hoc wireless networks, which I guess would solve that problem, except then the laptops would have to keep switching from one network to the other, one for internet and one for the printer. I'm sure there's a better way...